# Button states - press and re-press

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, onclick

I would like to know how to perform two actions on the same button. For example: if I press once the button shows me a toast that says "the button was pre-selected" and if I press it again the same button that shows me a toast that says "it was re-selected".

In summary, I want to perform two actions, each time you click on one of the two options depending on which is the last one you perform. If you made option 1, then do option 2 when it is pressed again and if it is pressed again, then do option 1.

Comment: So put a variable some appropriate place that controls what the button's click handler will do on the next click, and have the handler up date that variable appropriately on each click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use any kind of variable to check such a thing. Since you only have 2 states (First Click / Second Click), you can use a `Boolean`.

For example:

```
Boolean myBoolean = true;

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          if (myBoolean) {
          //Do the action for the first click
          myBoolean = false;
          } else {
          //Do the action for the second click
          myBoolean = true;
          }
     }
});
```